# What is the relationship between PyTorch and Torch?

Tags: lua, pytorch, torch

There are two PyTorch repositories :

- https://github.com/hughperkins/pytorch
- https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch

The first clearly requires Torch and lua and is a wrapper, but the second doesn't make any reference to the Torch project except with its name.

How is it related to the [Lua Torch](http://torch.ch/)?

Comment: Is the first repo really official?? Isn't that just a fork of `pytorch`?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Here a short comparison on pytorch and torch.

**Torch:**

> A Tensor library like `numpy`, unlike `numpy` it has strong GPU support.
> Lua is a wrapper for Torch (Yes! you need to have a good understanding of Lua), and for that you will need LuaRocks package manager.

**PyTorch:**

> No need for the LuaRocks package manager, no need to write code in Lua. And because we are using Python, we can develop Deep Learning models with utmost flexibility. We can also exploit major Python packages likes `scipy`, `numpy`, `matplotlib` and `Cython` with PyTorch's own autograd.

There is a detailed discussion on this on [pytorch forum](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/roadmap-for-torch-and-pytorch/38). Adding to that both PyTorch and Torch use [THNN](https://github.com/torch/nn/tree/master/lib/THNN). Torch provides lua wrappers to the THNN library while Pytorch provides Python wrappers for the same.

PyTorch's recurrent nets, weight sharing and memory usage with the flexibility of interfacing with C, and the current speed of Torch.

For more insights, have a look at this discussion session [here](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/torch-autograd-vs-pytorch-autograd/1671).

Comment: Is pytorch development related to torch at all or is the naming just a coincidence?

Comment: The essence of the question is: "is there any relationship between the two?", and this answer does not really address it.

Comment: This answer is confusing. 

Which one of hughperkins/pytorch and pytorch/pytorch is "Torch" and which one is "PyTorch"?

Answer (score 16):

*2023+ answer*

**Torch** ([`torch/torch7`](https://github.com/torch/torch7)) is the original implementation, primarily in C with a wrapper in Lua. The project was started in 2013 by IDIAP at EPFL. Later, other companies joined the efforts, including Facebook (now Meta Platforms). Development stopped by 2019.

**PyTorch** ([`pytorch/pytorch`](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch)) is indeed a [continuation of Torch](https://soumith.ch/posts/2021/02/growing-opensource/), rewriting the core in C++ and with an equally-important interface in Python (which was and remains the focus). The project was started in 2016 by researchers at Facebook (now Meta AI), and was [taken over by the PyTorch Foundation](https://ai.facebook.com/blog/pytorch-foundation/) (part of the Linux Foundation) in late 2022.

---

Somewhat confusingly, the Python package for **PyTorch** on `PyPi` is just called [`torch`](https://pypi.org/project/torch/). Fortunately, if you'd try to `pip install pytorch` (a dummy empty package), you'll get a clear error: `You tried to install "pytorch". The package named for PyTorch is "torch"`.

On `conda`, rather, the package is called [`pytorch`](https://anaconda.org/pytorch/pytorch) (under the channel/namespace `pytorch`).

Regardless of the package manager, in Python code you [**`import torch`**](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/basics/quickstart_tutorial.html).

---

P.S.: as for the other project you mentioned, [`hughperkins/pytorch`](https://github.com/hughperkins/pytorch), it's obvious by now that it didn't flourish; it ended development in 2016.

Answer (score 15):

Just to clarify the confusion between both pytorch repositories:

- `pytorch/pytorch` is very similar to (Lua) Torch but in Python. So it's a wrapper over THNN. This was written by Facebook too.
- `hughperkins/pytorch`: I have come across this repo when I was developing in Torch before pytorch existed, but I have never used it so I'm not quite sure if it is a wrapper written in Python over (Lua) Torch which is in turn a wrapper over THNN OR a wrapper over THNN and Lua. In both case, this is not the original version of Torch. It was written by Hugh Perkins when there was no Python alternative for Torch.

If you are wondering which one to go for, I would definitely recommend `pytorch/pytorch` as it communicates directly with THNN, is written by the people who made THNN and is continuously maintained. `hughperkins/pytorch` does not seem to be maintained anymore.

Comment: To add, any paper that mentions PyTorch is almost certainly referring to `pytorch/pytorch`, which is also vastly more popular on github