# are pytorch and torch compatible in code?

Tags: python, pytorch

I followed the website instructions:

```
pip install transformers torch accelerate
```

After the installation, the following code works

```
import torch
```

But, the performance was slow in Mac M1. I then installed

```
pip install pytorch
```

Without any code modification, the program seems okay. However, are we supposed to do some coding optimization from torch to pytorch?

Comment: This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75836941/10732351) should cover all of your questions.